# Which metric is used in Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection

I've been studying and using the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html) for a couple of weeks. I've successfully trained a model. Now that it's ready, I'm diving into the details about the training and something that I couldn't find an answer is:

**Which kind of evaluation metrics was used during the train?**

I'm using the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017 pre-trained model and in the config file, I have:

```
eval_config : {
   num_examples : 40
}
```

I thought initially that I was using some kind of logarithmic loss metric but searching in-depth in the [repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/legacy/train.py), I couldn't find anything helpful that prove what kind of metric I'm using, neither what was the loss function used. The training output looks like this:

[image]

Hope you could help me with this! :)

Comment: This kind of information is available in the papers, not much in the documentation, for SSD: https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I thought that it would be something called inside a function in the tensorflow's repository and it would be explicit which kind of metrics it was using.

Comment: Yes sure it should be somewhere in the code, but that does not mean it will be easy to find, modern convolutional object detectors are quite complex

Comment: I agree, I've been browsing the files and couldn't find anything related to it... The paper that you linked me, I couldn't find the part where it explain the metric that it was using. @Dr.Snoopy could you show it to me?

Comment: It is what is called "Training objective" in the paper

Comment: Reading a bit more. The multibox is the loss function used right? but that means loss function = evaluation metric? I may be missing something in the paper, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Researching more about metrics and reading more [here](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#evaluating-the-model-optional). I've finally found out that I wasn't using any metrics during the training. Those kind of metrics would be used only if I had something like:

```
eval_config : {
   num_examples : 40,
   metrics_set: 'pascal_voc_detection_metrics'
}
```

The documentation about available metrics to be used are available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/evaluation_protocols.md):

Answer (score -1):

Mostly in CNNs metric is `Accuracy` and the loss is `categorical_crossentropy`, thought it depends highly on your model